# Confusing notation regarding number of prime factors

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to understand the number theoretic aspects of this statement from the Probablistic Method page 44.

> The second moment method is an effective tool in number theory. Let $\nu(n)$ denote the number of primes $p$ dividing $n$. (We do not count multiplicity though it would make little difference.) The following result says, roughly, that "almost all" $n$ have "very close to" $\ln \ln n$ prime factors.
>
> Theorem 4.2.1 Let $\omega(n) \rightarrow \infty$ arbitrarily slowly. Then the number of $x$ in $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ such that
> $$
> |\nu(x)-\ln \ln n|>\omega(n) \sqrt{\ln \ln n}
> $$
> is $o(n)$

Firstly, what is the difference between $\nu(n)$ and $\omega(n)$? On Wikipedia, it says $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors.  What is different from the number of primes dividing $n$?

Secondly, what does it mean to "converge slowly"?

Comment: Really strange. I never read some other notations that $\omega(n)$ for the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ and $\bigomega(n)$ for the number of prime factors of $n$ with multiplicity considered. But since it is clarified what is meant here, it is OK. Interesting is the claim that it makes not much difference whether we consider multiplicity or not for this result.

Comment: See also the Erdös-Kac-theorem

Answer (score 4):

The quoted source is using $\nu(n)$ for the number-of-distinct-prime-factors function and $\omega(n)$ for something else. True, Wikipedia and many other sources use $\omega(n)$ for the number-of-distinct-prime-factors function, but that's not the case here.

You can ignore the words "arbitrarily slowly" without changing the mathematical meaning. The idea the author is trying to emphasize is that $\omega(n)$ might be growing at a slow rate (like $\log n$) or an even slower rate (like $\sqrt{\log n}$ or $\log\log n$ or ...), but the statement is still true for all such functions. (Note that the statement gets stronger the slower $\omega(n)$ grows.)